# Java failed to set property of an object

Tags: java

This is really strange, I have defined a class `S.Buffer` with a private field named `consumed`:

```
public static class Buffer implements Output, Appendable, CharSequence {

    /**
     * The value is used for character storage.
     */
    private char[] value;

    /**
     * The count is the number of characters used.
     */
    private int count;

    /**
     * track if {@link #toString()} method is called
     */
    private boolean consumed;
    ...
}
```

And there is a method named `reset`:

```
    public Buffer reset() {
        this.setLength(0);
        this.consumed = false;
        return this;
    }
```

As shown above I expect the `consumed` field value to be `false` after calling `reset()`, however this is not the case some how, and this can be revealed with the following screenshot of intellij IDEA:

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong here?

**Updates**

This happens during stepping into a unit tests, and the unit tests failed, it means the value is **NOT** set. However if I run the unit tests directly, it will pass.

I tried many other thing, e.g. use `int` or `AtomicBoolean` to replace boolean, all the similar result.

Comment: I tried, for me consumed becomes false

Comment: Is it a IntelliJ issue or the value is really not set to false ? Add a print of in your method, it should help you.

Comment: Does get reproduced if you compile it without IntelliJ by using `javac` and run through command line?

Comment: I think that what you are seeing is an anomaly / bug in Intellij's debugger.

Comment: @StephenC I will downgrade intillj and try again

Comment: It is really wierd, but if I had to guess I'd say it is InteliJ debugger bug

Comment: Don't IDEs use an object's `.toString()` to display it in debuggers? Does the whole thing work without the debugger? Your `toString()` should probably be idempotent and not change the state of the object. It's meant for debugging purposes, after all.

Comment: It could also be an issue with the memory model; i.e. different threads reading and writing without proper synchronization.  Trust what you are seeing when running the unit test w/o the debugger.  Debugging often causes memory anomalies to "change".

Comment: Robert is right! My shame I totally forgot that toString() reset consumed flag. @Robert do you minid putting your comment into answer so that I can give you the credential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toString()` should probably be idempotent and not change the state of the object. It's meant for debugging purposes, after all. IDEs use an object's `.toString()` to display it in debuggers. Your state may be set and then changed when the debugger shows it to you.